# Execute JavaScript when Select Element Has Only 1 Option

Tags: javascript, html

I have a `select` element in an HTML form. The options of this element are populated dynamically. When there is more than one option I have some JavaScript execute when the user selects which option they would like.

However, when the `select` element only has one option I would like to have the JavaScript submit automatically. I tried setting the option to `Selected` and adding `OnSelect`. I don't think an `OnLoad` would work either.

This is the HTML for when there is only 1 option:

```
<select name="acctnumber_box" id="acctnumber_box" onSelect="fillDistributorAcctNumber (value)">                                 
  <option selected="selected"><%=customerNumber %> &nbsp; <%= customerName %></option>
</select>
```

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: How is it being populated?

Comment: Add an `onchange` to the select, check the number of options, then do the respective task.

Comment: This select element is being populated by looping through the entries in a hash table.  I know if only have one entry by the count on the hash table.

Comment: I can't use the onchange event because the one and only entry is selected on page load when there is only one entry.  I don't want to pursue adding a "Select Account" default entry because I'm trying to avoid having to make the user select an account if they only have one account.

Comment: When you say its dynamically populated, do you mean javascript populates it? or a server-side script populates it. If its server-side you could use (document) onLoad, and if its javascript you could add something to the function that populates the list.